# comparing an int variable to MSSQL query results Python via pymssql

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pymssql

I'm trying to compare a variable to query results in the following which are dates in yyyymmdd format. The database field LastUpdate is of type int.

When I test this, I think I am getting the false result because the query is a tuple compared to my variable as int.

Is there a way to convert the (20160422,) to an int?

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='', user='', password='', database='')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT Top 1 LastUpdate FROM tbl_Date')

myDate = 20160422

for row in cur:
    print(row)

    if row == myDate:
        print('true')
        #then do something
    else:
        print('false')

conn.close()
```

Comment: forgot to add. this is my output >>> 
(20160422,)
false
>>>

Comment: Have you tried simply taking the first item in the `row` tuple: `row[0]` ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your suggestion, I've got this working based as follows; I just wasn't sure how to access elements of an array in Python, I just needed a clue. Thanks again.

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(server='', user='', password='', database='')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT Top 1 LastUpdate FROM tbl_Date')

myDate = 20160426

for row in cur:
    print(row[0])

if row[0] == myDate:
    print('true')
    #then do something
else:
    print('false')

conn.close()
```